# waiting for a function to finish with completion handler fails

Tags: swift, asynchronous, completionhandler

I am trying to wait for an asynchronous function to finish before processing it's data (e.g. saving it to my database).

I have a function `loadFacebookDetails()` containing two tasks:

1. Loading Data from Facebook `makeRequest()`
2. Saving the Data to my Database `saveAndProceed()`

I need `makeRequest()` -> (asynchronous) to finish before handling the saving.

This is what I got so far:
I declared a `typealias FinishedDownload = () -> ()`

I created:

```
func makeRequest(completed: FinishedDownload){
.... // bunch of code
completed() // call that I completed my task at end of function


}
```

now I don't now how to call makeRequest in my loadFacebookDetails.

I also created this:

```
makeRequest { () -> () in
saveAndProceed()
}
```

and my saveAndProceed().
Does anyone now how to make this syntactical correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something like :

```
func makeRequest(completion : ( ( Bool ) -> Void)){
    //your stuff goes hre
    completion(true)
    //or
    completion(false)
}

func saveAndProceed() {
    //your stuff
}

func loadFacebookDetails() {
    makeRequest { (hasSucceed) in

        if hasSucceed {
            saveAndProceed()
        }else{
            //handle Error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried to implement this, but my makeRequest is still executed AFTER saveAndProceed

Answer (score 0):

```
 func makeRequest(url: String ,callback :@escaping (YourObject) -> Void , errorCallBack : @escaping (String) -> Void ){
            // if finish or success
           callback(objecttoSend);

           // or if failed
           errorCallBack(message)
    }
```

and call it like this

```
makeRequest(url: "http://", callback: {(Object)in
   // on ur first action
  }, errorCallBack: {(error)in
   // on ur second action
})
```